# how to write a not-so complex if-else statement in Bourne shell?

Tags: sh, freebsd

I'm trying to get a not-so complex if-else to work on my **FreeBSD box** but I'm getting error with the second part of the condition.

basically, this is what I'm trying to do

```
if not file-exists or (file-exists and string exists in file) then
 do this
else
 do something else
```

this is the actual code I'm using

```
if [ ! -f /boot/loader.conf ] || [[ -f /boot/loader.conf ] && ! grep -Fqx "zfs_l
oad" /boot/loader.conf ]; then
                echo "found"
        else
                echo "not found"
fi
```

It gives me an error about "[[". I tried adding/removing brackets to no avail.

I've also searched the net for similar examples but the ones I've seen are very simplistic (i.e. if var=value then do this)

I could separate the conditions into 2 "ifs" but I think it can be done in 1 and I'm want to know "advance" if-else in bourne as well. :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks :)

Comment: FYI, /bin/sh on FreeBSD is POSIX sh, not Bourne.

Comment: ...Bourne is a shell from the 70s; POSIX sh is a ksh88-derived standard from the early 90s. There's a lot of difference between them, generally for the better.

Comment: thanks. It's just that guides often equate /bin/sh = Bourne. You don't really see guides to posix sh scripting. They call it bourne scripting and that's what I've been using since. :)

Comment: Yup. I'm enough of a pedant to mistrust anyone who calls a guide to POSIX sh a Bourne guide to actually care about accuracy; there are *lots* of differences. (For instance, actual Bourne shells support using `^` as a pipe character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{ ... }` for grouping without the overhead and side-effects of a subshell (as created by `( ... )`). `[[ ]]` is a different syntax, only available in ksh derivatives such as bash, which replaces `[ ... ]` with a less-error-prone alternative; it isn't available in baseline POSIX shells.

```
[ ! -f /boot/loader.conf ] || \
  { [ -f /boot/loader.conf ] && ! grep -Fqx "zfs_load" /boot/loader.conf; }
```

Comment: didn't know about using braces in if-else. I've also seen examples using brackets. thanks much :)